# Electric field and conservation of energy

Tags: electrostatics, energy, electric-fields, capacitance

I have a question of conservation of energy. Let's say I have two charged plates, one positively charged and the other negatively charged. Both have a hole and an electric field exists between the two plates. Now, let's consider an infinitely far away positively charged particule. Its potential energy is zero, same for its kinetic energy, thus its mechanical energy is also zero. My question is as follows. If the particule gets between the plates by the positive side, it now has potential energy, thus its mechanical energy increased. Where did that energy come from? Even worse, when the particule gets out by the other hole, it has kinetic energy, thus free work has been done by the plates. This is impossible and it seems to violate energy conservation. I'm not in the field of physics, just an engineering student but this is question has bothered me for some time. For example, I don't get why ion engines consume energy since it seems that accelerating particules with an electric field is free. One possibility would be that we need to expand energy to get the particules between the plates since their mechanical energy increases but I don't know where that would come from. What's the catch?

Edit: When I'm saying two plates with a hole I mean something like that:
[image]

And the electric field between two finite charged plates is:
[image]

Comment: This is very unclear. What is the "hole"? A hole in the plates or is this hole the gap between them? You say the particle is infinitely far away then suddenly it's between the plates? If you move the charge toward the plates, you are **doing work** (there is an electric field) and therefore the particle's potential energy must change. It doesn't just suddenly appear as you imply. You may need to edit this question to make it more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Its potential energy is zero . . . . .*
A single charge by itself does not possess electric potential energy.

Electric potential energy is the property of a **system** which contains more than one charge.

In the example that you have given the system of charges you are considering, the charged particle and the charges on the parallel plates, starts with a certain amount of electric potential energy and then as it passes between the charged plates finishes with less electric potential energy with the difference being converted into kinetic energy.

This is really no different to the dropping of a ball on the Earth.  The Earth & ball system start with a certain amount of gravitational potential energy and as the ball falls the gravitational potential energy of the system decreases ant the same rate as the kinetic energy of the system (ball and Earth) increases.  But of course because the Earth is so mush more massive than the ball you do not notice the increase in kinetic energy of the Earth.

Answer (score 1):

> If the particule gets between the plates by the positive side, it now has potential energy, thus its mechanical energy increased. Where did that energy come from?

It comes from the work required to push it between the plates by the positive side. You cannot place it there without doing work.

Comment: I get it. I was thinking about two infinite plates (thus, electric field outside would be zero). For finite plates, there is an electric field outside so we have to expand energy to place the particule between the plates. And once the particule gets outside it will get attracted by the negative side, so in the end mechanical energy never changes: the electric field is conservative. Thank you, I think I have undertsood.

Comment: One last question. Assuming I combine the positively charged particule with a negative one once it got accelerated. Then it wouldn't be attracted back by the negative plate since it has not charge. Thus, we would have extracted energy for free, which is impossible. Once again, what's wrong?

Comment: In that case the potential energy of the pair of charges would have decreased. The additional extracted energy is equal to that lost PE